# Permission denied while creating TPU VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I encountered a similar issue when following the tutorial on using a cloud tpu VM to run [Jax code.](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/run-calculation-jax). The error message is

```
PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied on 'locations/us-central2-b' (or it may not exist).
```

This question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64224796/google-cloud-tpu-gcloud-compute-tpus-create-failing-with-permission-denied), but **it is completely different**. Most importantly, in the original post, people are using the Legacy node while the most recommended methods are using cloud TPU VMs, which according to google is the preferred method.

Comment: I wonder if TPU v4 are not yet Generally Available.

Comment: I have just talked with Google support. It is available now except you have to apply for it.

Comment: do you have a link to where one can apply? I couldn't seem to find it anywhere in their docs.